# Add events to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a trouble creating the DOM:

```
{
    ...
    DOM = DOM + '<td colspan="3" align="center">';
    DOM = DOM + '<div id="primero" onClick(imprimir());> plz </div>';
    DOM = DOM + '</td>';
    ...
    $('#test').html(DOM);
}

function imprimir() {
    console.log(' ready!');
}
```

but that onclick doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you wrapping your code in document ready? edit: sorry - are you saying that the DOM insertion is working? In which case the text above your code is misleading.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing an `=` in your `onclick` definition. Try like this:

```
DOM = DOM + '<div id="primero" onclick="imprimir();">plz</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DOM = DOM + '<div id="primero" onClick="imprimir();"> plz </div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't recommend playing with the dom like this. No need for hand quoting all those HTML tags and your asking for an error if you do it alot. Recommend you use:

`document.createElement('')`

`setAttribute('', '')`

`document.getElementById('').appendChild('')`